# After removing controller name from the URL using route setting why it redirect me to URL with controller name

Tags: php, codeigniter

After removing controller name from the URL using route setting why it redirect me to URL with controller name

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('user/dashboard');?>">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <td><input type="text"  class="login-inp" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Password</th>
                <td><input type="password" value="************"  onfocus="this.value=''" class="login-inp" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-size" id="login-check" /><label for="login-check">Remember me</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td><input type="submit" class="submit-login"  /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </form>
```

This is my route setting

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'user';
$route['(:any)'] = "user/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "user/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "user/$1/$1/$1";
```

when I click on the submit button it redirect me to  this URL

I do not want controller name is the URL

```
http://localhost/grant/user/dashboard
```

I want like this

```
http://localhost/grant/dashboard
```

I think route setting is fine there might be issue with the `.htaccess` file any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `route setting`. You need to use/edit `.htaccess` file.

Change from

```
$route['(:any)'] = "user/$1";
action="<?php echo site_url('user/dashboard');?>
```

To

```
$route['dashboard'] = "user/$1";
action="<?php echo site_url('dashboard');?>
```

**Note**

Comment/disable the following code before trying above code.

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "user/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "user/$1/$1/$1";
```

Comment: @Ricky I have updated my answer again. You need to change the action link from HTML Form too.

Comment: if I will change the action link so how it will find my controller name?

Comment: @Ricky please try above solution first. Let me know If it does not work.

Comment: I tried this and redirect me to the controller name I have dashboard index .Because I have another controller with dashboard name in my controller.

Comment: Thanks Hassaan I have tried all your answer again and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Ricky Please accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: @Ricky ,I think you means that after submitting the form,than it redirects to this url, ok, tell me when you submit the form,than what url you give in the controller function for redirection,if you give redirect('user/dashborad'); ..... yes it will be displayed in the url, you have to define route for dashboard/index and than redirect your request to this route.